# UDT can't send unsigned char*

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, protocols, udp-data-transfer

I use UDT library to send my data. But seems it unable to send unsigned char* data properly. On one side I send it like

```
int rc = UDT::sendmsg(socket, full_data, size, -1, true);
```

On another side I receive like:

```
unsigned char* data;
int size = 2500;
data = new char[size];

while (true) {
    int rc = UDT::recvmsg(sock, data, size);
    if (rc == -1) std::cout << "Error: " << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "Received packet of length" << rc << std::endl;
}
```

On both sides send/receive count bytes are same. But data is different. When I do kind of

```
std::hash<unsigned char*> ptr_hash;
cout << "Hash: " << ptr_hash(data);
```

I've got different hashes. In UDT sources there are lines:

```
UDT_API int sendmsg(UDTSOCKET u, const char* buf, int len, int ttl = -1, bool inorder = false);
UDT_API int recvmsg(UDTSOCKET u, char* buf, int len);
```

As you can see input parameters are char* but not unsigned char* or void*. Does this means that I should send only char* or use for example base64 to encode my binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, tricky...  You're hashing your pointer.

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash (under notes)

I'd recommend printing the hex value of what you're sending on both ends to confirm it's the same, and it should be.  If you're sending a null terminated string, you might be missing the null.  But that's probably not the case here, given you specify it's unsigned chars.

Comment: Yes, I found this, but forgot to write here. It is really sends ok. I did as u said: on both sides did hex-print of buffers and they were the same. But you first wrote correct answer =)